# How to use the embedForm in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I want to repeat the form "SportsDayForm" 38 times to create a "CalendarForm", so I used the embedForm in this way:

```
class CalendarForm extends sfForm
{
  public function configure()
  {

    $subForm = new sfForm();
    $form = new SportsDayForm();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 38; $i++)
    {
      $subForm->embedForm($i, $form);
    }

    $this->embedForm('calendar', $subForm);
   }   
}
```

The template is this:

```
<?php use_stylesheets_for_form($form) ?>
<?php use_javascripts_for_form($form) ?>

<form action="<?php echo url_for('calendar/'.($form->getObject()->isNew() ? 'create' : 'update').(!$form->getObject()->isNew() ? '?id_sportsday='.$form->getObject()->getIdSportsDay() : '')) ?>" method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
    <?php if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="put" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $form ?>
</form>
```

but the php return this fatal error "Call to undefined method CalendarForm::getObject() in D:\htdocs\soccer\apps\backend\modules\calendar\templates_form.php on line 4".

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calling `getObject` in you template. Most likely that's the problem. `getObject` is a method in `sfFormObject`. Your `CalendarForm` extends `sfForm`, not `sfFormObject`. It could be useful to post your template.

Comment: I added the template in my original post

Comment: Like i was saying, you are calling the method `getObject` in your template on lines 4 and 5. You probably need to extend a `sfFormObject` form in your `CalendarForm`, not a sfForm (maybe you need the `BaseCalendarForm`, which extends `sfFormObject`). Otherwise that form doesn't have an 'object' to get and play with.